# Need help about accessing a JSON file using JavaScript without the use of any servers

Tags: javascript, json, localhost

I'm just beginning with JavaScript and I was wondering if I can access a JSON file on the localhost without the use of any servers (like WAMP). I was planning to just read the contents of a JSON file and reflect its contents to an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes you can.

Make an XMLHttpRequest against a static file such as: resources/myJSON.json (the extension is merely for organization, you can call the file whatever you want really).

Parse the response as JSON.

Obviously the file must contain a properly formatted JSON object of data, but as long as that's the case, you can load static JSON from a file to "simulate" remote connectivity to a server.

When you're browsing a file as: file:// on your system, it should treat the relative paths correctly.

Comment: Depending on your browser, you may need to alter the security settings to enable the XMLHttpRequest to load that file though.